# Storing UIColors in NSDictionary and retrieving them?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, uicolor

I need to return a specific UIColor for a given index.
I am trying to basically store the UIColors as NSArrays

> TypeColors = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
>
> **@"1"**, [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],[NSNumber
>   numberWithFloat:0.5],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil],
>
> **@"5"**, [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],[NSNumber
>   numberWithFloat:0.5],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1],[NSNumber
>   numberWithFloat:1.0], nil]
>                       , nil]; //nil to signify end of objects and keys.

And here I want to retrieve the UIColor back from that dictionary:

```
a = 5;
NSArray* colorArray = [TypeColors objectForKey:a];
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:[colorArray objectAtIndex:0]
green:[colorArray objectAtIndex:1] blue:[colorArray objectAtIndex:2] 
alpha:[colorArray objectAtIndex:3]];
```

It always returns me a zero, anyone knows why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:[[colorArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]
green:[[colorArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] blue:[[colorArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] 
alpha:[[colorArray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue]];
```

The parameter to be sent there is cgfloat and not NSNumber

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) The order of things in `initWithObjectsAndKeys` are objects and then their keys.  Yes, it is intuitively backwards.

2) The key is not an integer `5` but an `NSString` `@"5"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your UIcolor to  Nsstring first before save it in dictionary as follow :

```
    -(NSString *)convertColorToString :(UIColor *)colorname
    {
    if(colorname==[UIColor whiteColor] )
    {
       colorname= [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
    }
    else if(colorname==[UIColor blackColor])
    {
       colorname= [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    }
    else
    {
        colorname=colorname;
    }
    CGColorRef colorRef = colorname.CGColor;
    NSString *colorString;
    colorString=[CIColor colorWithCGColor:colorRef].stringRepresentation;
    return colorString;
}
```

and when you want to fetch the value from dictionary than you need to convert string to color as follow

```
    -(UIColor *)convertStringToColor :(NSDictionary *)dicname :(NSString *)keyname
{
    CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:[dicname valueForKey:keyname]];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:coreColor.red green:coreColor.green blue:coreColor.blue alpha:coreColor.alpha];
    //NSLog(@"color name :%@",color);
    return color;
}
```

exa :

here dicSaveAllUIupdate is my dictionary and i saved my view background color in it.

```
 [dicSaveAllUIupdate setObject:[self convertColorToString: self.view.backgroundColor] forKey:@"MAINVW_BGCOLOR"];
```

and i will retrive it as follow

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[self convertStringToColor:retrievedDictionary:@"MAINVW_BGCOLOR"];
```

Hope this help to you ...